# how to add tab bar controller from the second view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

Im beginner to IOS app development learning.
I have a login screen as my first view controller and i need the second view controller to be a tab bar view controller .with 4 different tabs and i have 4 different XIB's for them.

some one help me to go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way you can do is Present the login screen modally when the app starts from your tab bar controller first screen, add code for presenting login screen in viewWillAppear and after login dismiss the screen. You can create TabBarController in appDelegate like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


    UITabBarController tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init]; 


    FirstViewController *firstVC =  [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstVC" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: firstVC];     

    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondVC" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondVC]; 

   tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: firstNavController, secondNavController, nil];

    tabBarController.selectedIndex=0;
    tabBarController.delegate = self;

UITabBarItem *item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Movies" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MoviesTAB.png"] tag:1];

    [firstVC  setTabBarItem:item1];

    UITabBarItem *item2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Music" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"musicTAB.png"] tag:2];
    [seconfVC setTabBarItem:item2];

    tabController.tabBar.translucent  = NO;
    tabController.tabBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    tabBarController.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.window.rootViewController = tabController;
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is use storyboard and there just have one initial UIViewController and from that make segue to UITabBarViewController. 
http://youtu.be/a_DCTSTv1Mw

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it through xib make a UITabBarViewController and add viewControllers to the array of object of that UITabBarViewController's object.

Sample code :

```
    NSMutableArray *arrViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIViewController *tabController;
    UIImage *tabImage ;
    NSString *tabTitle;

    for (int i= 0; i < 3; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                tabController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
                tabImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1.png"];
                tabTitle = @"Text";
                break;

            case 1:
                tabController = [[ImageDemoViewController alloc] init];
                tabImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2.png"];
                tabTitle = @"Image";
                break;
            case 2:
                tabController = [[TableDemoViewController alloc] init];
                tabImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon3.png"];
                tabTitle = @"Table";
                break;
        }
        // set the image and title using some properties of UIViewController

        tabController.tabBarItem.image = tabImage;
        tabController.tabBarItem.title = tabTitle;

        //add objects to array

        [arrViewControllers addObject:tabController];

        [tabController release];
    }

    _baseController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    _baseController.viewControllers =  arrViewControllers;

    [arrViewControllers release];
```

Answer (score 0):

go to your appDelegate

1.create  a viewController for login screen.

```
LoginViewController *viewController1 = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
```

2.create a navigationController with root view your login ViewController.

```
UINavigationController *nVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
```

3.make navigationController to root view of window.

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.nVC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Now go to Touch-Up-Inside method of login button in LoginViewController.

1.After validation of password and userId initialise your viewControllers for tabbar and TabbarViewController.

```
UiViewController ...*yourViewControllers,..,
UITabBarController *YourtabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
```

2.Now add these viewControllers to your tabbarController.

```
 YourtabBarController.viewControllers = @[  YourViewController1,YourViewController2,YourViewController3,......];
```

3.Finally push this tabbarController to navigationControllere.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:YourtabBarController animated:NO];
```

Comment: I used your logic and it's displaying the tabbarcontroller after the login but...first, I can't seem to find a way to get rid of the back button (why would the user want to go back to the login screen after logging in); second, I can't set the title of the page or add buttons to the nav bar in the tabbar controllers...is that normal behavior?

Comment: If you are talking about navigation bar on the top with back button then you can remove it using:nVC.navigationBarHidden = YES; inside of appDelegate.

Comment: Oh so it's THAT nav bar which is shown...Got it, thanks!